# Knockout JS throws "not a function" error from within foreach

Tags: javascript, function, knockout.js

I'm facing the following issue with Knockout. I have a list set up that is populated with some values. This all works great and I get my dropdown items just fine. It also has a click function, that registers the value of what is being clicked. This works fine with a console.log but it absolutely refuses to update a KO observable that I set up. It ONLY screws up when it's inside the `<ul>`, if I move the `<a>` line in the HTML out of the `<ul>` to a different section of the page, it works without issues. Likewise, if I tell Javascript to update the "dropdownSelectedA3" value with something if a different button is clicked. I'm thinking it's looking in the wrong place or something but I can't seem to figure this out.

Also tried:

- Changing "this.dropdownSelectedA3(answerUserA3)" to "viewmodel.dropdownSelectedA3(answerUserA3)" but same issue occurs
- Removing $parent also does not fix it, unfortunately

Can someone perhaps point out my mistake?

My code:

Relevant HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu3UL" data-bind="foreach: dropdownAnswersAssignment3">
         <li>
           <a data-bind="text: $data, click: $parent.logAnswerA3" href="#"></a>
         </li>
        </ul>
```

Relevant JS (in my viewmodel):

```
this.dropdownAnswersAssignment3 = ko.observableArray([C1M5OptionsActive.A3.option1, C1M5OptionsActive.A3.option2, C1M5OptionsActive.A3.option3, C1M5OptionsActive.A3.option4]);

var answerUserA3

this.dropdownSelectedA3 = ko.observable("...");

this.logAnswerA3 = function(answer) {
    answerUserA3 = answer;
    this.dropdownSelectedA3(answerUserA3)
}
```

Comment: where is `dropdownAnswersAssignment3` in your model ? can you show it here

Comment: Appologies, updated.

Comment: Scope problem, `this` inside the `logAnswerA3` function refer to the function itself so not the same `this` as the one outside that function.

Comment: Hi Gilles, I thought so too but I've also tried changing "this.dropdownSelectedA3(answerUserA3)" to "viewmodel.dropdownSelectedA3(answerUserA3)" but same issue occurs.

Comment: From what I see `dropdownAnswersAssignment3`  belongs to the same `VM`. If so, just remove   `$parent.` in your element binding.

Comment: I gave that a shot earlier also (because this is how all my other click functions work, that is, without the $parent thingie), but then it complains of the following: "Unable to process binding "click: function (){return logAnswerA3 }" logAnswerA3 is not defined"

Comment: Please read https://www.airpair.com/knockout/posts/top-10-mistakes-knockoutjs. Look at #2 and look at the example code provided and I think all will be clear to you.

Comment: Thank you so much Namrehs. It was the "var self = this" that solved it. I saw that in other people's code but didn't fully understand it. Chapeau!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bind click event inside your `foreach` loop, either you need to have click function inside your VM where your array exists or you can reference it to the parent view model by having a nested View Model so in that case you are able to refer `click event` to your parent VM. In fact for each element of your array you create a new instance of `itemViewModel` then each of them point to the parent click function
Example :https://jsfiddle.net/9aLvd3uw/234/

HTML :

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: dropdownAnswersAssignment3">
   <li>
        <a data-bind="click:$parent.logAnswerA3,text: name"></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

JS :

```
var itemViewModel = function(text){
 var self = this;
 self.name = ko.observable(text); 
}
function demoViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  //fake data
    var arr =  [ 'Click A', 'Click B', 'Click C'];
   self.logAnswerA3  = function (item){
     alert(item.name() + " just Cliked");
   }
   self.dropdownAnswersAssignment3 = ko.observableArray($.map(arr, function (element) {
        return new itemViewModel(element);
    }));
}
var mm = new demoViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(mm);
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice overview, it was the "var self = this" bit that I didn't fully understand.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem, you just want to put a object of the list in an observable when click on it. You could to this:

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.objectClicked = ko.observable("...");
  self.objectList = ko.observableArray(["Object 1", "Object 2", "Object 3"]);

  self.click = function(data) {
    self.objectClicked(data);
  }
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: objectList">
  <li>
    <a data-bind="text: $data, click: $root.click"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
<p data-bind="text: $root.objectClicked"></p>
```